# How to mock a class method of NSObject using OCMock

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, nsobject, ocmock

Is there a way to create an instance of an NSObject? I'm trying to mock a class method from NSObject and am getting an error that `objc[86140]: no class for metaclass 0x1065c0e38`.

```
- (void)testChainMethodCalled
{
  id controller = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[MyController class]];
  MyController *controller = controllerId;

  id object = [[OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[NSObject alloc] init] ];
  [[[object expect] classMethod] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(chainMethod) object:nil];

  [controller callTestMethod];
  OCMVerifyAll(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When mocking class methods, you should be using `OCMClassMock`. You're using `partialMockForObject` which mocks the object instance and not the class itself.

For your example:

```
id objectMock = OCMClassMock([NSObject class]);
```

Then you can mock any method on the class like such:

```
OCMStub(ClassMethod([objectMock classMethod])).andReturn(mockValue)
```

Where classMethod is the class method you're mocking and mockValue is the fake value you're mocking out for that class method

See http://ocmock.org/reference/#mocking-class-methods for more details on this